# Cannot run SSH or send commands to /etc/init.d/ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-8.04

When I attempt to execute any commands such as **/etc/init.d/ssh restart** or **/etc/init.d/ssh start**, I get no output. It just goes to the next command line (Ubuntu Hardy). I can even pass in junk parameters such as **/etc/init.d/ssh asldkfjalskfdj** and i get no warnings or error messages, it just goes to the next line. I can check in my processes:

```
lsof -i :22
```

and don't see my ssh process. I also don't see my SSH process when i run:

```
netstat -na --inet
```

Any troubleshooting suggestions?

THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH!! I have no idea how i got rid of it, but apparently i killed my SSH install. A quick **sudo apt-get install ssh openssh-server** did the trick!! I really appreciate you all taking time out of your day to help me out!

Comment: try sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script will exit immediately if the `/usr/sbin/sshd` binary can not be found and executed. Can you `ls -l /usr/bin/sshd`?

Comment: I don't have a /usr/bin/sshd though i do have a /usr/bin/ssh, the output of /usr/bin/sshd is:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 xuserx xuserx 316640 2008-05-14 14:39 /usr/bin/ssh

Comment: In that case you're missing the actual sshd daemon. Reinstall the openssh-server package.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting it in debug mode and look for errors.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -def /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: looks like i don't have a /usr/sbin/sshd file which is most likely  part of the problem. This server has worked for the last ~6 months, and last time i was in it i certainly didn't go around deleting files in my usr/sbin folder, no matter...though i would like to have the file back. Any suggestions?

Comment: i don't use ubuntu but i think you should be able to install with "sudo apt-get install ssh"

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to debug what a shell program is doing, you can **use the `set -x` option** to instruct the shell to display each expanded command before it executes the command:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh foo
$ sudo sh -x /etc/init.d/ssh foo
+ set -e
+ test -x /usr/sbin/sshd
+ umask 022
+ export SSHD_OOM_ADJUST=-17
+ test -f /etc/default/ssh
+ . /etc/default/ssh
[…]
```

Comment: Output is as follows. Looks like i don't have a /usr/sbin/sshd. I have no clue how i could have accidentally deleted it. Any clue how I might go about getting back my long lost file?
+set-e                   /                             
+ test -x /usr/sbin/sshd /                                 
+ exit 0                 /